# Как анимировать движение круга по окружности другого большого круга с помощью SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я хочу перемещать маленький круг по окружности большого круга, используя  CSS или SVG

```css
@keyframes moveAround {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#small {
  animation: moveAround 2s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
      <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
      <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/q/66838390/7394871 от участника  [@Subato Patnaik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13847690/subato-patnaik).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66838390/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Элементы изображаем с помощью градиентов `radial-gradient`. Анимацию вращения имитируем с помощью трансформации `transform: rotate`.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; animation: circle 3s linear infinite;
  background:
    radial-gradient(yellow, yellow 9px, transparent 10px),
    radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent, transparent 30px, red 31px, red 49px, transparent 50px, transparent 100%);
  background-position: 0 -40px, 0 0;
}

@keyframes circle {0% {transform: rotate(0deg);} 100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Такую анимацию конечно можно выполнить и с помощью позиционирования фона `background-position`, но тогда получится добрая простыня стилей, потому что позиционирование будет смещаться на пиксель-в-пиксель, так как анимация вращения должна быть по кругу. Поэтому приведу самый простой пример анимации с помощью позиционирования фона. При том, что анимация передвижения элемента не по кругу, правило `@keyframes` уже включает в себя пять кадров.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; animation: circle 5s linear infinite;
  background:
    radial-gradient(yellow, yellow 9px, transparent 10px),
    linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent, transparent 50px, red 51px, red 69px, transparent 70px, transparent 100%),
    linear-gradient( 0deg, transparent, red 0px, red 19px, transparent 19px, transparent 100%);
  background-position: -40px -41px, 0 -16px, 0 0;
}

@keyframes circle {
  0% {background-position: -40px -41px, 0 -16px, 0 0;}
  25% {background-position: 41px 41px, 0 -16px, 0 0;}
  50% {background-position: -40px 41px, 0 -16px, 0 0;}
  75% {background-position: 40px 41px, 0 -16px, 0 0;}
  100% {background-position: -40px -41px, 0 -16px, 0 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

*Решение только для CSS без SVG*

```css
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 20px solid #2493AB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #EF6868;
  animation: moveAround 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes moveAround {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(40px);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66839919/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Вы должны указать, вокруг какой координаты круг должен вращаться. По умолчанию это координата 0,0, но вы хотите, чтобы она вращалась вокруг центра большого круга.

В CSS вы делаете это с помощью [transform-origin:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

```css
#small {
    transform-origin: 60px 50px;
    animation: moveAround 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes moveAround {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
        <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
        <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66838620/7394871) от участника  [@Sphinxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869660/sphinxxx).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

*SMIL SVG решение*

Для вращения шарика используйте [animateTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform)

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
      <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
      <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" >
       <animateTransform
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="0s"
         dur="3s"
         values="
           0 60 50;
           360 60 50"
          repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
      </circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

*Вращение шарика с паузами в конечной точке*

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
      <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
      <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" >
       <animateTransform id="an"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="0s;an.end+1s"
         dur="2s"
         values="
           0 60 50;
           360 60 50"
           /> 
      </circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

*Вращение вперед-назад*

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
      <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
      <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" >
       <animateTransform
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="0s"
         dur="4s"
         values="
           0 60 50;
           360 60 50;
           360 60 50;
           0 60 50;
           0 60 50"
          repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
      </circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66840345/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>